# Polymer and working with external JavaScript Libraries

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

With Shadow DOM, I can easily use external CSS frameworks like bootstrap nicely and it will only apply to my scope which is nice (example [here](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/github-repos-polymer/blob/331058448552bbb0a59e5534f04921f668c6afe4/github-repos.html#L13)).

However, this doesn't apply to JavaScript libraries as far as I know. If I, for example, need to work with jQuery on my web component, I basically make it available for entire page. What is the recommend way to work with external JavaScript libraries with Polymer? How should I handle cases where my web component (which is distributed through bower) needs one version of foo.js and the consumer needs another?

Comment: browserify and requirejs are common choices to modularize javascript files. With ECMAScript6, modules will be built-in. You could require different versions of jquery, shim them and do all sorts of things.

Comment: @JevZelenkov hmm, I have been using requirejs for a while now but never knew it was possible to ensure you can load a specific version of library. How can I ensure that my web component will only be working with foo.js 2.0.0 for example (even if the consumer already has 1.9.0 loaded). If the library is attaching itself to `window` object, it may screw up the consumer AFAIK, correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no JavaScript encapsulation solutions I know of.

1. Check if js encapsulation solutions exist, e.g. check zonejs and alternatives.
2. You may do it yourself but this will require you to devote some time to it. E.g. I've encapsulated Babel with `with` statement as shown [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2344) (not tested).